# Proof for Queue in BFS consists of vertices of distance k and k+1

Tags: algorithms, graphs, proof-techniques, correctness-proof, breadth-first-search

***For any vertex v reachable from s, BFS computes a shortest path
from s to v (no path from s to v has fewer edges)***. 
In order to prove the above proposition, The author of the book has stated that we first need to
**Prove by induction : 
 The queue always consists of zero or
more vertices of distance k from the source, followed by zero or more vertices of
distance k + 1 from the source, for some integer k, starting with k equal to 0**

I am confused about how would one go about doing the proof by induction for the above statement?
How should I approach the proof?

Comment: You will need to use the order of the stack, that is: prove that vertices of distacne $k$ were inserted before vertices of distance $k+1$ (again, in induction), and then you can use the ordering to show this statement

Comment: So my inductive hypothesis would be to assume: vertices of distance k are in queue, followed by vertices of distance k+1. Based on this assumption, I will have to prove that vertices of distance k+1 will be in queue followed by vertices of distance k+2. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is what you need to do